# Randomly pulling p different elements of a set

Tags: algorithm, random, set

I need a function `pull(S,p)` that takes a an ordered set `S` and a number `p` with `p < n = |S|`, such that it returns a list of `p` randomly chosen and different elements of `S`.

Assume that `s_i`, `i = 1, ..., n`, is the `i'th` element of `S`. The problem would then be to randomly generate `p` different indices in the range `{1, ..., n}` and pulling the elements with these indices.

How do I achieve this? It is not enough to generate `p` random numbers in this range, as that might cause collisions, and repairing collisions seems inefficient.

Comment: @hivert Yes, this question has been asked many times. It's too bad that the duplicate you linked doesn't have Floyd's sampling algorithm as an answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you take out an element of set, you swap the last element of the set with this element. Then you reduce the size of set by 1. Then you repeat getting element by Random()*size of set.

Comment: This requires me to reorder items in a previous set, which potentially has negative consequences. This can be avoided by creating a new set of `n` elements, but then the algorithm is `O(n)`. Can we reduce the function to `O(p)`?

Comment: You can keep a log of how you modified the set. The log is just an array of indexes of element you take out every time. After you get the result, you can easily recover the set by this log. Both time and space are O(p)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to shuffle the indices `{1, ..., n}` and take the first `p` elements as the indices

Comment: How do you propose to shuffle them?

Comment: [Fisher Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)